# Do these metahumans match up with real comic versions?

Tags: dc, the-flash-2014, arrowverse, the-flash

At the end of Season 2 Episode 21,

> Zoom calls several Earth-2 metahumans together to wage war on Central City.

Here are a few screenshots:

> [image: first]
>  [image: second]
>  [image: third]

Are these metahumans pulled directly from the comics? Put another way, do they correspond to actual DC comic characters or are they just generic, nameless metahumans created for the show?

Comment: I can't get the spoiler tag to hide the video but the scene in question can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9e-sdpNO3lk

Comment: Unless you can get a script or a behind the scenes agent, it is unlikely you will be able to tell much about these metahumans. They don't appear to be anyone I am familiar with but the scene is dark, the costumes darker, and it doesn't appear to be any particular group being represented.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze - There's a lady with electric powers on the right of the third picture (also near the middle in the second picture) that might resemble Livewire. That's what prompted the question.

Comment: Given that DC's psychological investment has been more in heroes than villains, it COULD be, but without that behind the scenes interaction, we simply can't know. The upside is because there are so few heroes, DC is free to plunder their vast archive of villains from whatever superhero they want (besides Batman's iconic Rogue's Gallery) which we assume belongs to Gotham, at the moment.

Comment: Also, there are a few that I figured would be more recognizable than others like the guy on the far left of the group with the green flames coming off his hands, feet, and head. Also the one on the far right with the white suit and red hair/head/helmet/whatever.